# How to split one group into seperate using php

Tags: php

I want split one group AS follow

```
splitGroups("11133355557777") ➞ ["111", "333", "5555", "7777"]
```

Anyone have idea then let me know

Comment: Have you made any attempt at coding this for yourself?

Comment: Actually I am not getting how to start this

Answer (score 1):

With php version 5 above this will work link to execute
Link to an example https://paiza.io/projects/qfRZ07OP3OviWCVsUbdFtQ

```
function splitGroups($str){
  $arr = [];
  $i=0;
  $sub = '';
  while($i!=strlen($str))
  {
    $sub .= $str[$i];
    if ( strlen($str)-1 == $i || $str[$i] != $str[$i+1] ){
      $arr[] = $sub;
      $sub='';
    }
    $i++;
  }
  return $arr;
}
```